# Formula to search for a value in a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with several cells in one column. Each cell has identical conditional formatting:

- In 1 cell value equal to `='Y'`
- In 2 cell value equal to `='N'`
- In 3 cell value equal to `='?'`

What I would like to achieve is, if all 7 cells contain "Y" as the option then a separate cell will display "Yes", but if any of the cells contain "N" as the selection then the separate cell will display "NO".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more: use the MATCH function: MATCH("N",a1:a7)
If the "N" is found on the range a1:a7, it will return a number, otherwise, #N/D

Then use ISNUMBER and IF: =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("N",a1:a7)));"NO";"YES")

PS: for M$-excel use ';' and in OOffice use ','

Comment: for exact match you should have a zero as third argument in MATCH like =MATCH("N",A1:A7,0)

Answer (score 1):

Try using COUNTIF, e.g. if cells are A2:A8 then

`=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A8,"Y")=7,"Yes","No")`